# How to mix 2 textures using different UV maps on one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I have a model: tree with few branches. The main tree trunk is laid on one UV map, and all branches laid on the second uv map. I have a textures ready for both of them, but i'm having trouble mixing them.

Here is a little picture to illustrate: [image]

I want to mix those 2 textures and see them both on the same object. I have tried using "Mix Shader", and it works, but it only lets me see one of my textures at a time. Or if i put mix slider on 0.5, i can see both of them half muted. I also tried using "Add Shader" to mix my textures, and for some reason it produces something that also looks like a half muted combination of my 2 textures. And i would like to see them both simultaneously at the full power.

I also have searched the solution, but was unable to find anything that handled my situation. All tutorials that i found handled the case where few UV sets was identical and textures was laid on each other just by using "Factor" attribute. In my case UV are radically different and textures do not lay on each other, so i was unable to use anything i learned from those tutorials i found.

Comment: have you tried two materials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured things out. I don't really understand why it works, but i was able to resolve my problem by inputting alpha of one of the textures into "Mix shader" factor.

This is a easy stuff, but i didn't expect it to work, because my UV sets are very different, and if merged together will interpenetrate each other and create a mess, so i didn't consider doing alpha of one of my textures as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

All this work apparently is required currently in Blender, because in *Properties Editor → Object Data Properties Tab → UV Map Panel* the UV Maps created there have their *Active Render* but this a Radio Button feature; Can only have one at a time.

I suspected something could be achieved through a Node system such as the Shader Editor since it is plausible to control and combine certain 'visibility' issues from there… but I'm not knowledgeable enough on that field to know what would be a valid approach.

My current issue is that I was almost being successful at completing a cartoon's Eye Rig using UV Warp Modifier, with 2D Shader Editor's Nodes (instead of Image Texture) and that would depend on
a single Eyes Mesh Object with —the crazy part— a Mirror Modifier; so that single Mesh Object required 2 UV Maps (Symmetrically disposed in UV Editor) to be used respectively by each of the Left/Right UV Warp Modifier. But then came the problem: the Rig cannot control the side which UV Map in UV Map Panel is not being the one on **Active Render**; which is was also the cause of your issue as I understand.

I made some tests in *Shader Editor* but couldn't figure out how to solve this in some similar way as you explained.

Nonetheless, I was still able to solve the Rig, but at the cost of the *Mirror* Modifier, which I had to apply to make thinks easier (it would be really fashionable if it could be preserved).